# npm run prod not changing NODE_ENV to production

Tags: node.js, npm

Running on windows, node.js, and other dependencies are listed below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "dev": "SET NODE_ENV = DEVELOPMENT& nodemon backend/server",
    "prod": "SET NODE_ENV = PRODUCTION& nodemon backend/server",
    "seeder": "node backend/utils/seeder.js"
  }
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.10",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.2",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.9"
  }
```

TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
$ npm run prod

> shop@1.0.0 prod C:\*****\shop
> SET NODE_ENV = PRODUCTION& nodemon backend/server

bash: SET: command not found
[nodemon] 2.0.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node backend/server.js`
DEVELOPMENT
Server started on PORT: 4000 in DEVELOPMENT mode.
MongoDB database connected with host: localhost
```

**When running `npm run prod` the server still runs in development mode.**

**I have already tried clearing cache and deleting node_modules to refresh build but it does not work.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows it may be because of whitespaces that you are getting the error - can u try below,

> set NODE_ENV=production&&nodemon backend/server

You can learn more from docs - https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-the-difference-between-development-and-production

Comment: && doesn't even work and results with & is still the same

Comment: Are you still getting bash: set command not found error?. Do you mind trying some other terminal.

Comment: bash: set command not found error is removed but the probelm is still there